# SED - Replace text between placeholders

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, terminal

I need a few of you SED wizards to give a noob a hand....

I'm using SED to replace text between some placeholders. 
The problem is that they are on separate lines (and SED hates that apparently).

The text I need to replace is between '#SO' and '#EO', like this:

```
#SO
I need to replace this text
#EO
```

I have come up with this:

```
sed -ni '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/#SO\(.*\)#EO Test/1/REPLACEMENT/ p }' foo.txt
```

I'm just starting to get to grips with SED, so I could be totally wrong, but any advice would be great.

Comment: When you write something cryptic and convoluted  like that - don't you wonder if sed is REALLY the right tool for the job? sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line but for anything else just use awk. Basically if you find yourself using more than "s" and "g" with sed then your almost certainly using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sed` as shown below:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
#SO
I need to replace this text
#EO
line 3

$  sed -n '/#SO/{p;:a;N;/#EO/!ba;s/.*\n/REPLACEMENT\n/};p' file
line 1
line 2
#SO
REPLACEMENT
#EO
line 3
```

How it works:

```
/#SO/{                       # when "#SO" is found
  p                          # print
  :a                         # create a label "a"
    N                        # store the next line
  /#EO/!ba                   # goto "a" and keep looping and storing lines until "#EO" is found
  s/.*\n/REPLACEMENT\n/      # perform the replacement on the stored lines
}
p                            # print
```

Comment: You beauty! Thanks for that. Works perfectly.

Comment: @dogbane is it possible to only replace text in the first "block" that matches ? For example I have 2 "#SO - #EO" blocks and I only want to replace inside the first one

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sed -n '/#SO/,/#EO/{s/.*/REPLACEMENT/;}' file
```

More details see this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76105/how-to-sed-a-range-of-lines).

Answer (score 0):

You can use patterns to specify a range of line for sed to work on.
see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29

```
sed -n '/#SO/,/#EO/ s/.*/changed/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
$ cat file
#SO
I need to replace this text
#EO

$ awk '/#EO/{f=0} {print f ? "replacement text" : $0} /#SO/{f=1}' file
#SO
replacement text
#EO
```

If not, show some more representative input.